# Problem while Installing on Windows 7 laptop

Tags: 14.04, lts

I trying to install Uubuntu 14.04 LTS on my laptop, which is running on Windows 7 OS. But while installing the installation guide does not recognize my Windows 7 OS. It says this computer has no OS found in it whereas it has Windows 7. So finally it is giving me an option to install only Ubuntu and not alongside with Windows 7.

Or it is giving a partition option which I'm not sure how to perform. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it doesn't recognize it but as a solution you can install Ubuntu on an external drive so when you want to get to windows you just go to the boot menu or unplug the drive